# Flex indenting false paddings, text doesn't center in some cases

Tags: css, text, flexbox, alignment, center

I've got a problem with making flex sections in equal sizes like shown here (don't mind button style):
[image: How it should look like when all styling done, showing how flex should behave]

I'd like to make headings and text equal size in every section, so text won't slide down, right or left, and in some weird cases my text doesn't follow a rule text-align: center; although it's written in dev tools.

[image: Showing the issue]

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>XeDA+ - sklep internetowy</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-flex">


        <main class="about-us-75 d-flex flex-wrap text-center">
            <article class="fb-100 d-flex flex-wrap">
                <section class="fb-33 d-flex flex-wrap">
                    <h4 class="heading-about-us">Możesz nam zaufać - my nie gryziemy</h4>
                    <p>No może trochę, tych co są wobec Ciebie niesympatyczni. Nasza firma jest skupiona na kliencie i dokładamy wszelkich starań, aby dobrać pogodny i doświadczony zespół.
                        Dla nas liczy się przede wszystkim dobro klienta oraz satysfakcja z przemyślanego zakupu.</p>
                </section>
                <section class="fb-33 d-flex flex-wrap">
                    <h4 class="heading-about-us">Reklamacje to u nas nie problem. Pomagamy je rozwiązać.</h4>
                    <p>Dokładamy wszelkich starań, aby obsługa klienta w naszej firmie była na najwyższym poziomie, stąd też przyjmujemy na nasze stanowiska tylko doświadczonych pracowników i szanujemy prawa konsumentów oraz nabywców naszych usług i produktów. U nas nie ma sporów, są tylko pozytywne rozmowy :).</p>
                </section>
                <section class="fb-33 d-flex flex-wrap">
                    <h4 class="heading-about-us">Jesteśmy otwarci na propozycje 24/7.
                        Twoja opinia jest dla nas istotna.</h4>
                    <p>Nie wrzucamy waszych opinii i feedbacku do kosza, przekazujemy je wprost do naszego zespołu ds. projektowania i logistyki. Na każdą opinię odpowiadamy, oraz odpowiadamy czy planujemy wprowadzić zaproponowane funkcjonalności, a jeśli to podajemy również przewidywalny termin realizacji :).</p>
                </section>
            </article>


            <article class="d-flex flex-wrap fb-100 text-center">
                <section class="fb-33 d-flex flex-wrap">
                    <h4 class="heading-about-us">Dlaczego my, a nie - on, ona, ono.</h4>
                    <p>Nie my, lecz WY. Wy, klienci stanowicie źródło dochodów dzięki którym możemy się rozwijać. Jesteśmy jedyną firmą, która nakłada tak dużą uwagę na dobro klienta. Nie próbujemy Cię przekonywać do naszej firmy, jesteśmy zadowoleni z Twojej decyzji nt. firmy, którą wybierzesz tak długo, jak ty sam jesteś szczęśliwy :).</p>
                </section>
                <section class="fb-33 d-flex flex-wrap">
                    <h4 class="heading-about-us">Co oferujemy? Czym się zajmujemy?</h4>
                    <p>Zajmujemy się mnóstwem rzeczy. Między innymi jest to:</p>
                    <p>- satysfakcja klienta,</p>
                    <p>- logistyka i rozwiązywanie problemów,</p>
                    <p>- tworzenie stron internetowych,</p>
                    <p>- pomoc zdalna,</p>
                    <p>- korepetycje z angielskiego.</p>
                    <p>W przyszłości może będzie więcej rzeczy, które będziemy oferować :).</p>
                </section>
                <section class="fb-33 d-flex flex-wrap">
                    <h4 class="heading-about-us">Gwarancja jakości.</h4>
                    <p>U nas możesz spodziewać się jakości i doświadczenia jeśli jest inaczej oferujemy miesiąc czasu na zwrot kosztów w przypadku tworzenia stron i korepetycji w przypadku gdy nie podniosły one poziomu wiedzy. Jesteśmy również skłonni porozmawiać i wyjaśnić nieścisłości oraz zawsze stoimy po stronie klienta :).</p>
                </section>
            </article>
        </main>


        <aside class="about-us-25 d-flex flex-wrap text-center">
            <article class="fb-100 d-flex flex-wrap">
                <section class="fb-100">
                    <h4 class="heading-aside">Dowiedz się o promocjach!</h4>
                    <h4 class="heading-aside">Zapisz się na newsletter.</h4>
                    <label for="email"><input name="email" type="email"></label>
                    <input type="submit" value="Zapisz się">
                </section>
            </article>
            <article class="fb-100 d-flex flex-wrap">
                <section class="fb-100">
                    <h4 class="heading-aside">Promocja!</h4>
                    <p class="text-aside">Z kodem "COVID-19" oszczędzasz na korepetycjach z języka angielskiego o 25!</p>
                    <p class="text-aside">Ucz się języka na odległość, chroń nauczycieli i siebie od możliwego zagrożenia.</p>
                </section>
            </article>
        </aside>


    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/* fonts used */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400;1,700&display=swap');
/* cleaning garbage */
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
/* use that font */
body {
    font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
}
/* container flex */
.container-flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

/* about us */
main.about-us-75 {
    flex-basis: 75%;
}
.d-flex {
    display: flex;
}
.flex-wrap {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.fb-100 {
    flex-basis: 100%;
}
.fb-33 {
    flex-basis: 33%;
}

main>article section {
    padding: 5% 2% 5%;
}
main>article:nth-child(2) section {
    padding-top: 10%;
}

main>article section>h4 {
    color: #707070;
    font-size: 26px;
}
main>article section>p {
    color: #707070;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.heading-about-us {
    padding-bottom: 15%;
}


/* newsletter and offers - aside */
aside.about-us-25 {
    flex-basis: 25%;
}
aside>article section {
    padding: 5% 2% 5%;
}
aside>article:nth-child(2) section {
    padding-top: 10%;
}
.text-center {
    text-align: center;
}
.heading-aside {
    font-size: 26px;
    color: #707070;
}
.text-aside {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #707070;
}
```

I don't know why id doesn't scale well. Maybe some paddings are wrong. Thank you for reading.

Comment: I found that adding to texts flex-basis: 100% solves the issue but why some p tags don't need that to display their text in center?

Comment: I don't see the problem in the code you posted ([jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6t45ajud/)). And your comment above isn't clear (*"...adding to texts"*?).

Comment: Yeah when I added to paragraphs flex-basis: 100%; they started to be in the center, some of them didn't need this option to begin with, so I'm confused

Comment: main article section * {
    flex-basis: 100%;
}
by writing this I have now this: https://imgur.com/a/lYoGY2S

How to make the right section (aside) align with the left one (main)